# Why my ScrollController throws an error when navigating back and forth or restart?

Tags: flutter, listview, scrolltop

I have this `ListView.builder()` that has a controller that will `animateto(index: 50, ......)` in the `buidler` method, it works perfect, it does the animation and goes to the index, but the only problem is that when I go to another screen and back to the `listView.builder()` or when I do restart, an error is thrown :

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_activity.dart': Failed assertion: line 613 pos 15: 'to != null': is not true.
```

what I understand is that there is a method in `animateto()` that is null. Here is the `ScrollController()`:

```
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

scrollController.animateTo(
       scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
       duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
       curve: Curves.easeOut);
```

**UPDATE**

I am sure now that it is the position of the scrollController that throws this error, I checked the library, and the `to` argument is the position where it will animate to.

**Edit**
ListView.builder() code:

```
ListView.builder(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    reverse: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      var link = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Link'];
                      var uploader =
                          snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Uploader'];
                      var likes = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Likes'];
                      var like = likes.toString();
                      bool liked;
                      if (int.parse(like) > 0) {
                        liked = true;
                      } else if (int.parse(like) == 0) {
                        liked = false;
                      }
                      final videoPlayerController =
                          VideoPlayerController.network(link);
                      chewieController = ChewieController(
                        allowMuting: true,
                        autoInitialize: true,
                        deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: orientation,
                        allowFullScreen: true,
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
                      );
                      scrollController.animateTo(
                          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                          curve: Curves.easeOut);
                      return link != null
                          ? SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Chewie(
                                    controller: chewieController,
                                   ),
                                ..............................
```

**Full Error**

```
    ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for VideoPlayerController:
setState() called after dispose(): _MaterialControlsState#da2c1(lifecycle state: defunct, not
mounted)
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in
the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error
```

Comment: I think you're using this scroll animation in `initState` and the reason you're getting this error is that Listview is not rendered yet. Try adding a delay in the scroll and see if the error is gone!

Comment: nope, using it in builder: method in ListView.builder()

Comment: as I said it works at first but when I navigate or restart, it throws that error.

Comment: Share the code for `listview.Builder`

Comment: did just now, .

Comment: Add complete error message.

Comment: just updated it.

Comment: This error seems different from the one you shared before.

Comment: That's because it throws these two errors away from each other so I didn't realize that there is another error.